# Turning on outlining per default on asp-files in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

After I upgraded to SP1 of visual studio 2010 outlining on asp-files have been turned of by default, in other words every time I start visual studio I have to manually turn on outlining again. How can I get this turned on by default?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Try recording a macro of you turning on outlining.
2. Extract the "meat" of the macro and create a new macro that's hooked into the SolutionEvents_Opened event of the EnvironmentalEvents module in your macro project.  The signature would look a bit like this:

   ```
   Private Sub SolutionEvents_Opened() Handles SolutionEvents.Opened
       MsgBox("Solution opened!")
   End Sub
   ```

   You would of course need to replace the MsgBox call with the actual act of turning on outlining, which you would get from your recorded macro.
3. Try opening a solution in VS and see if your macro runs.